# How to specify file types when indexing Solr

Tags: solr

I've been indexing a directory of folders/files containing html pages, docs, ppts, pdfs..etc. I noticed a type of file called LOG that is being indexed and I don't want it to be indexed because the contents aren't needed.

To index to Solr i've been using this command (i am a windows user so i use the simple post tool): `java -Dc=collection -Dport=4983 -Drecursive -Dauto jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder` Instead, I tried to do the following command to exclude LOG files:

```
java -Dc=collection -Dport=4983 -Drecursive -Dfiletypes=xml,json,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder
```

Solr refuses to index, and throws errors (#400 http). -Dfiletypes should be an actual command i can use, but Solr doesn't seem to like it. I even tried [] around the list of file types and it won't work. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: What is the Solr log saying about the 400 error?

Comment: @MatsLindh "SimplePostTool: WARNING Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP responsecode : 400 for URL: /"

Comment: That's the error from the post tool, not the Solr log. The Solr log will contain more information about what exactly the reason for the 400 error was.

Comment: @MatsLindh sorry, here it is: SolrException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe5 (at char #10, byte #-1)

Comment: That seems to be caused by invalid (i.e. non-utf-8-data) being submitted in your example with explicit filetypes data. Since you dropped `-Dauto` in your second command line, could it be that the wrong content-type header is set when you don't include that command? That would make the UTF-8 parsing bork

Comment: @MatsLindh You're right! After I added back -Dauto, everything works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add -Dauto, it works!

```
java -Dc=collection -Dport=4983 -Drecursive -Dauto -Dfiletypes=xml,json,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder
```